# Angle Chasing in geometry in triangle

Tags: triangles, angle

In triangle $\Delta ABC$, $\angle CAB = 30^{\circ}$ and $\angle ABC = 80^\circ$. The point $M$ lies inside the triangle such that $\angle MAC = 10^\circ$
and $\angle MCA = 30^\circ$. Find the value of $180^\circ – \angle BMC$ in degrees .

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: I tried hard using angle chasing but couldn't get answer . Please can someone help me ?

Comment: Well, please do show how exactly you used Angle Chasing, so you can show that you have put in some effort and allow others to build up on what you have done so far.

Comment: Start by mentioning which angles you *could* get using angle chasing. Put it all in the post above. Enclose math in dollar signs (\$), and use "\angle" for the $\angle$ sign.

Comment: I have edited your question. Please add a diagram and/or mention which angles you managed to chase. It seems your question involves more than angle chasing, it could require auxiliary construction.

Comment: After spending 5 minutes with the problem, I am convinced that the problem is well defined.  I suspect that you (the original poster) have made some mistakes: [1] Assuming that this problem is from a book or class, there **almost certainly** were theorems or previously solved problems that led up to this problem that are pertinent.  You haven't **edited your query** to report what these theorems/solved-problems are.  In effect you are violating mathSE's [no-clue](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) policy. ...see next comment

Comment: [2] You haven't **edited your query** to explicitly show any work that you have done.  Please do **not** respond with a comment.  Instead, please edit your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Hint:

Extend lin segment $AM$ and draw line segment $BF$ such that $\angle CBF = 10^0$.

Can you see $ABFC$ is cyclic with $\angle ACF = \angle ABF = 90^0$?

That leads to center of the circle on $AF$.

If $\angle ABG = 20^0$ then can you see $AG = BG = CG$?

You can then show $\triangle BCG$ is equilateral.

Now, as $\angle MGC = \angle MCG = 20^0$, $\angle GBM = \angle CBM = 30^0$.

You also know $\angle BCM = 40^0$.

And adding both $\angle CBM$ and $\angle BCM$, you get $(180^0 - \angle BMC)$.

Comment: I actually had an answer, but this user has not edited so I have not posted it. This answer is nice, though.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thanks for your comment and glad you liked the solution. I generally avoid posting in such cases and I was contemplating but as I had come up with a solution, thought of omitting some details and post with hope that OP would fill in the blanks. I admit I was a lot stricter about not posting answers without seeing effort from OP when I joined the site earlier in 2020 but I saw a lot of veterans on the site been for years post answers without seeing effort from OP and me watching, and slowly I became a little more flexible :)